# connect xbox controller to ubuntu

Tags: 16.04

How can i connect an xbox controller to my ubuntu machine. in bluetooth mode only.

Here us my config:

```
sudo bluetoothctl
agent on
default-agent
scan on
connect XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
trust XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
```

here is my oytput

```
fredy@fredy-MacBookPro:~$ sudo bluetoothctl
[sudo] password for fredy: 
[NEW] Device XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX Xbox Wireless Controller
[bluetooth]# trust XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
[CHG] Device XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX Trusted: yes
Changing XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX trust succeeded
[bluetooth]# pair XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
Attempting to pair with XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
Failed to pair: org.bluez.Error.AlreadyExists
[bluetooth]# connect XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
Attempting to connect to XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
[CHG] Device XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX Connected: yes
Failed to connect: org.bluez.Error.Failed
[CHG] Device XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX Connected: no
[bluetooth]#
```

i try:

```
sudo apt-get install xboxdrv
sudo apt-get install --install-recommends jstest* joystick xboxdrv
```

then reboot

Thanks for your time !

Answer (score 0):

i installed it from here (https://github.com/paroj/xpad)

```
sudo git clone https://github.com/paroj/xpad.git /usr/src/xpad-0.4
sudo dkms install -m xpad -v 0.4
```

i works for me !